# How to change color of checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to change look and feel of checkbox that means it should change to green when checked else it should be red.

Any idea how to do it in Jsp or Javascript??

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkIt(cb)
{
    cb.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = cb.checked ? 'green' : '';
}
```